# Getting autocomplete on a dynamic function's parameters

Tags: typescript

So I have this object

```
const obj = {
    property1: {
        func: ({num1,num2,operation}:{num1: number, num2: number, operation: string}) => "p1"
    },
    property2: {
        func: ({obj}:{obj: {[key: string]: string}}) => "p2"
    }
} as const
```

I need a function that can trigger the "func" functions inside this object using the property name like this:

```
function getFuncFromObj(property: string, parameters: {[key:string]: any}): any {
  return obj[property]['func'](parameters)
}

getFuncFromObj("property1", {num1: 2, num2: 5, operation: "+"})
```

but this is not safe, and it doesnt provide autocomplete, and it also removes the whole use of ts for types

so I tried using this function

```
function getFuncFromObj<T extends keyof typeof obj, K extends Parameters<typeof obj[T]["func"]>[0]>
(key: T,parameters: K): string {
    return obj[key]["func"](parameters)
}

getFuncFromObj("property1", {num1: 2, num2:5, operation: "+"})
```

this works in terms of autocomplete but ts throws an error when I try inputting the parameters

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ num1: number; num2: number; operation: string; } | { obj: { [key: string]: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ num1: number; num2: number; operation: string; } & { obj: { [key: string]: string; }; }'.        
  Type '{ num1: number; num2: number; operation: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ num1: number; num2: number; operation: string; } & { obj: { [key: string]: string; }; }'.
    Property 'obj' is missing in type '{ num1: number; num2: number; operation: string; }' but required in type '{ obj: { [key: string]: string; }; }'.

318     return obj[key]["func"](parameters)
                                ~~~~~~~~~~
```